# A protocol, class protocol, both of them or

Tags: swift, class, swiftui, delegates, protocols

scratching my head over this, I'm creating a framework to be used by others and need to define tons of delegates, something in the line of:

```
protocol MyDelegate {
...
}
```

so I can then have it as:

```
var delegate: MyDelegate?
```

Fine, that works great for SwiftUI's views, go there, receive notifications, easy, convenient. But not everyone uses SwiftUI or not only use the delegates in structs, come the stuff that implements MyDelegate is a class, I'm facing a possible strong reference cycle thingy. And I can't do

```
weak var delegate: MyDelegate?
```

Sure, I can switch over to

```
protocol MyDelegate: AnyObject {
...
}
```

But then I can't use it in structs/views. Would be awesome if I can mark the non-class version as weak and have Swift internally not increment the counter if you pass a class based something but thats not the case so I'm puzzled and can't decide.

Ruling out leaving only the AnyObject version, one possible way is to double each of the protocols - one variant with AnyObject, one without, and ofc everywhere it is set and declared and... etc, that includes doubling documentation, great code pollution...

Any ideas? :(

Comment: How about just adding a remove delegate function? That way, you don’t have to worry about whether the reference is weak or not.

Comment: Delegation is not very common in SwiftUI, you can pass closures instead

Answer (score 0):

Just document (loudly) that nilifying the delegate reference, if needed to prevent a retain cycle, is up to the client when the delegate is a reference type. This is not entirely unusual; Cocoa / UIKit has some delegates that must be "manually" nilified in this way.

Comment: I can think of more sophisticated approaches but really, in the absence of actual code, the original question is just hand waving and therefore so is this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Additional: I was thinking about closures too, but a single protocol can have like 10 different functions, a closure won't work, although it is really neat solution for some of the cases.

Overall, after a discussion with customers I decided to go for class protocols with weak var, memory safety is of a bigger concern than convenience. Even if written with big red in documentation, people read docs only if something is badly broken usually :)

Will create view model examples for SwiftUI and the observable object class will be the one implementing the code rather than the View struct thus avoiding the limitation. Granted, not as elegant and not as simple, but in this case...